# Prove that f is analytical under given conditions

Tags: calculus

So I will skip defining analytic function here and jump straight to what prove is required:

If f satisfies the following conditions, then it is analytic:
On any closed interval [a,b], there is a constant M (depending on [a,b]) such that for all $k = 1,2,...,|f^{(k)}(x)| \leq kM^k$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

Comment: What are your thoughts, what have you tried, where are you stuck? Do you know Taylor's theorem (**with remainder**, e.g. in Lagrange's form)?